# How to tag MariaDB questions that also apply to MySQL

Tags: discussion

I'm using MariaDB server 10.3 currently at my job, which so far has successfully been a direct drop-in replacement for MySQL 8 (I use the MySQL 8 documentation as my reference when managing our MariaDB servers). If I need to ask a question about, say, a query that I'm wondering if could be improved, I would love to tag it with `mysql` and `mysql-8.0` so that:

1. It gets more attention than if I tagged it with only `mariadb` and `mariadb-10.3`.
2. It's obvious that the question applies to MySQL as well as MariaDB, e.g. when people find it in the future

So how should I tag these questions? Would it be appropriate to tag both, so my question ultimately would end up with 4 tags?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [tagging] help page:

> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question. Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.

Based solely on that, I'd say it's fine to use both MySQL and MariaDB tags for a single question, assuming the question does not use specific features from MariaDB that aren't supported in MySQL (or vice-versa).

To head-off tag pedants, you may consider adding a sentence in your question to the effect of "I've tagged this question with *both* MySQL and MariaDB since the answer applies equally to both, and I'm trying to attract expert answers from both crowds".